# Opposite of "the league of extraordinary gentlemen"?

Tags: analogy

If "the league of extraordinary gentlemen" consists of good guys what do we call the analogue group consisting of bad (but not necessarily uncultivated) guys? I am thinking of members like Prof. Moriarty, Mr. Hyde, and Arsene Lupin). They are certainly no gentlemen, are they?

Context: I am looking for a title for an RPG adventure.

Comment: Unless you can say *which* word you want an antonym for, no answer is remotely possible. (And although it's theoretically possible to give an antonym for a phrase, it's far more difficult than giving an antonym for a single word.)

Comment: The characters name is Mr Hyde spelt with a y like the places near me East Hyde and West Hyde. He's also a member of the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen they aren't all good they just display abilities beyond those of ordinary people.

Comment: Sorry Aufwind, I'm flagging this for closure as Primarily Opinion Based, since no "correct" answer is possible. For further guidance, see [ask] and [Real Questions Have Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A suitable phrase might be [**rogues' gallery**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogues%27_gallery#English), originally a set of photographs of convicted and alleged criminals, now used to describe a [group of ne'er-do-wells or villians](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RoguesGallery).

Examples: [1](https://www.globalpolicy.org/international-justice/rogues-gallery.html), [2](https://www.brokenghostimmersives.com/the-rogues-gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

A retinue of inglorious rascals. Seems to cover it nicely for me, don't you think or don't you?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a detailed explanation for your answer, preferably with a published example. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)